SFINAE's behaviour is unexpected when using in class template
I'm trying to implement a CRTP pattern, the base class will check whether the derived class contains specified member method OnOk:
template <typename Op, typename HasOnOk = void>
struct is_inheritable : std::false_type {};

template <typename Op>
struct is_inheritable<Op, decltype(std::declval<Op>().OnOk())> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_inheritable<T>::value>>
class Base {};

class Derive : Base<Derive> {
public:
    void OnOk(){}
};

Strangly, the code doesn't compile, the error message is as follow:
prog.cc:18:27: error: template argument 2 is invalid
 class Derive : Base<Derive> {
                           ^

Can anyone explain the reason, Thanks!

by the time you instantiate Base<Derive> the class Derive is incomplete and you cannot test for presence of members

This is not a case where CRTP should be used. CRTP should provide a common implementation (like std::enable_shared_form_this) not validate child class.

I sometimes use a pure virtual method when I want to ensure derived classes implement it. Though I think Marek is correct and this isnt actually a case for CRTP in the first place
